# How to Open a url according to input choice in Teams bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using Microsoft teams bot framework and want to open a url according to the input choice the user has made.

[image]

```
{
    "type" : "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [

        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Download sample file Attachment",
            "size": "Large",
            "Weight": "Bolder"

            
        },

        { 
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "id": "template_choice",
      "style": "compact",
      "label": "select the template",
      "isMultiSelect": false,
      "value": "1",
      "choices": [
        {
          "title": "template 1",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "title": "template 2",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "title": "template 3",
          "value": "3"
        }
      ]
    }

    ],

    "actions": [
      {
          "type": "Action.Execute",
          "verb": "down",
          "title": "Download" ,    
          
          "data": {
            "action": "executeAction"
          }
              
          }
      
  ]
 
}
```

I have made an adaptive card with input choice set and a download button as shown here and the button is Action.Execute, and i want to open a url to download the templates but open the urls according to the choice in the input choice set.
How would one go about opening different url when the button is clicked according the input choice in the adaptive card?

Comment: To open different URLs based on the user's choice in the Adaptive Card, you need to handle the user's choice in your bot's code. When the user clicks the "Download" button, an invoke activity is sent to your bot with the user's choice. Your bot can then send a response with an `openUrl` action that has the URL corresponding to the user's choice.

Comment: hey, @Prasad-MSFT - I want this to be done in one click, the when the user clicks "download" and the url should open.
Also how would i pass the url to it , as the json file for the adaptive card does not support a variable?

Comment: The way you intend to implement doesn't seem to be feasible.